# How to approach dataset splitting for building time-series models?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, supervised-learning, train-test-split

Suppose I have 100 observations of time series data $x_1,...,x_{100}$, and that I want to split the data into a train set, a validation set, and a test set. I know that the train set must have smaller indices than the validation set and test set, but I am torn about how to handle the validation and test sets.

To illustrate, suppose that my train set is $x_1,...,x_{80}$.

Option 1: Let my validation set have smaller indices than my test set, e.g. give indices 81-90 to the validation set and indices 91-100 to the test set. But in this case, the test set is "further away" from the training data, and I would expect this to underestimate performance.

Option 2: I could position the test set before the validation set, in which case the problem is the opposite, where hyperparameters are chosen based on performance on data that is "far away" from the training data.  For some reason, this sounds a bit better than option 1.

Option 3: I could have my validation and test sets alternate observations, so the odd indices could go to the validation set while the even indices could go to the test set. This sounds nice, but there would probably be a lot of correlation between validation and test set, and I don't think the performance on the test set would still be an unbiased estimator, which would partially defeat the purpose of having a separate test set.

Is one of these three approaches clearly better than the others? Is there a better 4th option?

Comment: A very interesting and well-phrased question.

Answer (score 1):

By choosing alternating indices serial correlations are broken in forming test and validation sets, so Option 3 is not advised. Option 1 and 2 are actually close to identical, only swaps the test and validation segments.
More rigours approach would be doing *temporal cross-validation*:

1. Rob J Hyndman's *evaluation on a rolling forecasting origin* is preferred in doing cross-validation. See [Cross-validation for time series](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/)
2. A bit more sophisticate approach is using secondary model in reconstructing missing points at random, to generate k-fold temporal
   cross-validation. See [Generalised learning of time-series: Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.09394v3)

But for basic sanity check both Option 1 and Option 2 are acceptable, given that series are stationary.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that, after evaluating and tuning against the evaluation set, you would then take your final set of tuning parameters and retrain on all data up to the end of evaluation. You could then use this model's forecasts to evaluate on the true out of sample test set. But there is no silver bullet for training a forecasting model so I agree with patagonicus that rolling origin evaluation can be useful, provided you have enough data.